# Javascript - Higlight red if date time is expired

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi folks im sure this is probably a simple question for alot of you. I have a a text field in a TD with a date "23/04/2015 9:23 PM" and I need that cell to simply to orange when its 30 minutes overdue and red if 60 minutes overdue.

I have this fiddle with an example of how the dates are laid out. But having no luck with the code. `http://jsfiddle.net/s3328ffo/35/`

Anyone have any idea where im going wrong here?

```
$('#timeTable tr td').each(function () {
    var dtTd = new Date($(this).html());
    var dtNew = new Date();
    // 15 minutes is 900000 milliseconds
    // getTime() doc - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

    if (dtTd.getTime() - dtNew.getTime() < 900000 && dtNew < dtTd) {
        $(this).parent('tr').addClass('min15');
    } else {
        if (dtNew > dtTd) {
            $(this).parent('tr').addClass('old');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I would recommend using a date parser library like momentjs... else there are multiple problems.... also depending on the local time to color the elements are also tricky as you can't depend on it always to be correct

Comment: I could be wrong but your fiddle looks like it is working to me.  When I change the date and time in the TD, within 15 minutes is orange, expired is red.  If you are expecting this to update in real time, you would need to add a timer

Comment: Given the way he wrote the example date in the question ("23/04/2015 9:23 PM"), it would seem he's using the DD/MM/YYYY format. The code, however, is reading it as MM/DD/YYYY format. It works correctly if you're using the latter format, but not if you're using the former.

Comment: Strange, i updated the fiddle link now to use the date format as 23/04/2015 9:23 PM which is what I needed http://jsfiddle.net/s3328ffo/35/.

Comment: You know what i just realized that I confused everyone with the fiddle code, the code itself highlights the TD when the time is 15mins about to expire. What I needed is to turn orange when it was 30 mins overdue and red when its 1 hour overdue. Looks like rich.okelly has the code I needed but will need to mix this in with IronFlare's code to convert my date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rich.okelly suggested, the dates are being parsed in MM/DD/YYYY format. To change the date to DD/MM/YYYY format, you could do something like this:

```
var dtSt = $(this).html().split(" ");
var dtAr = dtSt[0].split("/");
var dtTd = new Date(dtAr[1] + "/" + dtAr[0] + "/" + dtAr[2] + " " + dtSt[1]);
```

This will swap the month and day in the variable before parsing it as a date.

http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/s3328ffo/28/

EDIT:
I know that this issue has already been resolved, but I knew my code was somewhat inefficient and longer than it had to be, so I couldn't help but attempt to improve upon it. I managed to shorten it quite a bit, and I have a feeling that this will significantly improve performance.

```
var dtSt = $(this).html().split("/");
var dtTd = new Date([dtSt[1], dtSt[0], dtSt[2]].join("/"));
```

Comment: Thank you Iron Flare this help with the date conversion issue I had.

Comment: @DanielEllison The method of changing the month and day that I put in my answer initially was quite inefficient. I shaved off between 2 and 5 milliseconds on each row using a different method which I have posted at the bottom of my answer. (The new code is also shorter, which is another, though less-noticeable, benefit) I would recommend using this new code instead of the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Dates are tricky beasts.

I believe that your dates are being parsed in 'American format' eg MM/dd/yyyy.

Hence more things are going red than they should be.

See http://jsfiddle.net/mt8sf7gL/ for a working example, but js copied below for reference:

```
$('#timeTable tr td').each(function () {
  var when = Date.parse($(this).text()); // This can be changed from .text() to read the value from an attribute ifyou do not wish to display the date in this format
  var now = Date.now();

  if (now - when > 3600000) {
    $(this).parent('tr').addClass('old');
  } else if (now - when > 1800000) {
    $(this).parent('tr').addClass('min15');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rich this is the logic i needed for my code but was just missing the conversion for my date 23/04/2015 9:23 PM. I used IronFlare's code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright folks I got it working. I had to combine part of IronFlare's and rich.okelly's codes to get it to work like I needed. Thank you so much guys!

http://jsfiddle.net/mt8sf7gL/7/

```
$('#timeTable tr td').each(function () {
    var dtSt = $(this).html().split(" ");
    var dtAr = dtSt[0].split("/");
    var when = new Date(dtAr[1] + "/" + dtAr[0] + "/" + dtAr[2] + " " + dtSt[1]);
    console.log(when);    
    var now = Date.now();

    if (now - when > 3600000) {
        $(this).parent('tr').addClass('min60');
    } else if (now - when > 1800000) {
        $(this).parent('tr').addClass('min30');
    }
});
```